# Do kernel functions of integral transforms have any special properties?

Tags: analysis, integration, integral-transforms

From the [Wikipedia page on integral transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform), it states that:

> ...an **integral transform** is any transform $T$ of the following form:
>   $$ (Tf)(u)=\int^{t_2}_{t_1}K(t,u)f(t)dt $$
>   ...There are numerous useful integral transforms. Each is specified by a choice of the function $K$ of two variables, the **kernel function** or **nucleus** of the transform.

I was wondering **if the kernel function has to have any special properties in order for the integral transform to work**. On the bottom of the Wikipedia page, it shows some of the common kernel functions such as $\frac{e^{-iut}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and $e^{-ut}$ for the Fourier Transform and the Laplace Transform. However, as an example, with the kernel function $$ K(t,u)=\ln|t+u|,\space t_1=0,\space t_2=\infty $$ the integral transform would diverge for almost all $f(t)$. Or, for another example, the kernel function $$ K(t,u)=ut,\space t_1=-\infty,\space t_2=0 $$ also diverges for almost all $f(t)$. My thinking is that there has to be some certain property of the Fourier Transform and the Laplace transform that make it so they don't diverge for almost all $f(t)$. So, my basic question is whether a certain property has to hold in order for the integral transform to not diverge to infinity given any function $f(t)$.

Comment: Depends on what kind of $f$ you plan on applying it to.

Comment: Elementary functions I guess? The Laplace transform works for all elementary functions (from what I've seen, correct me if I'm wrong), so something similar to that.

Comment: No, it doesn't. For example, $e^{t^2}$ doesn't have a Laplace transform. The problem is that if you want to take the integral over all of $\mathbb{R}$ then you need to specify some growth condition on $K$, and exactly what growth condition you need is dictated by the growth conditions you specify on the $f$ you want.

Comment: So $K$ can't be or isn't easy to find given a group of functions for $f$ unless they all have the same growth conditions? Or am I misinterpreting what you said?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you want some conditions on $K$ for the integral operator to be well-defined you have to specify a class of functions $f$ that you want to integrate $K$ against. Without this data, you can't say anything. If the functions $f$ you want to integrate against grow very quickly then $K$ needs to decay very quickly.

Comment: Oh okay, so the reason the Laplace transform works is because it decays faster than most elementary functions can grow?

Comment: Yes, at least for suitably large $s$.

Comment: A more typical question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362011.